Janky `system` font in Firefox
I'm using the online version of WhatsApp and until a week ago, everything worked fine. Recently, on 2 out of 3 of my computers with Ubuntu, the font changed to the one in the screenshot:

This particular text has the font-family set to : "SF Pro Text", "SF Pro Icons", system, -apple-system, system-ui, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", "Helvetica Neue", "Helvetica", "Arial", "Lucida Grande", "Ubuntu", "Cantarell", "Fira Sans", sans-serif. I assume that I don't have SF* fonts, so the first thing that loads is the system font, which is rendered as above. Indeed, if I change any font to system, it becomes this pixelated one:

Importantly, this happens on Mozilla Firefox 124.0.2 (and not e.g. Chromium) and only on the two computers with an Nvidia GPU (not sure if that's relevant). It happens on both X11 and Wayland, Ubuntu 23.10.
Lastly, this is the current Firefox font setting:


FWIW I have the same font-family specification. The font that is actually displayed on my system (as shown by the Fonts tab of the DevTools window) is Ubuntu Regular. I suppose the system font points to Ubuntu Regular on my system, and to something more primitive on your system. The font on your system is non-aliased, which is an ancient setting on current systems. BTW I have a similar fonts setting in Firefox as you (only Noto Serif and Noto Sans instead of DejaVu) but this doesn't seem to be relevant for your issue.

I think there might be some Firefox overrride and not system-wide. On Chromium, the system font points to something normal and aliased.

This seems to be an issue in the Flatpak version of Firefox. The proposed solution there works fine:
mkdir -p ~/.var/app/org.mozilla.firefox/config/fontconfig/conf.d
cp /etc/fonts/conf.d/70-no-bitmaps.conf ~/.var/app/org.mozilla.firefox/config/fontconfig/conf.d


Try un-ticking 'Allow pages to choose their own fonts, instead of your selections above'. It worked for me.

I tried and it makes the fonts on WhatsApp nicer, yes. But I also want websites to choose their own fonts, so this does not fully work for me.
